# API Versioning and long running processes with nServiceBus and REST API

Tags: api, architecture, versioning, nservicebus

We are building a web API and using nServiceBus for messaging under the hood for all asynchronous and long running processes.

Question is when we spin off a new version of the API should we use a new set of queues?

Like, for the API version 1,

- blobstore.v1.inbound
- blobstore.v1.outbound
- blobstore.v1.timeout
- blobstore.v1.audit

and for the API version 2,

- blobstore.v2.inbound
- blobstore.v2.outbound
- blobstore.v2.timeout
- blobstore.v2.audit

Or should we strive to use the same set of queues with multiple message formats and handlers (assuming change of requirements and evolving message formats)?

I am trying to understand pros and cons in the long run from the architecture standpoint. Having a separate set of queues gives the flexibility of building, deploying and managing different API versions in isolation without worrying about compatibility and sociability.

Personally I am leaning towards to the latter but the challenges around compatibility and upgrades are not clearly understood.

If you have dealt with a similar scenario in the past, please share your experiences, thoughts, suggestions and recommendations.

Your time is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more frequent your releases, the less appropriate a queue-per-version strategy becomes, and the more important backwards-compatibility becomes (both in structure and in behavior).

Comment: Agreed, there will be multiple releases with-in the same version of the API and the message compatibility will be preserved across these releases. According to our current API strategy, major version changes take place only when there is a breaking change. But the point is this breaking change may not be related to messaging at all, it could be related to authentication, storage, etc.

So it’s the debate around queue versioning across major API version revisions regardless whether there are message revisions or not.

Answer (score 0):

The decision between going with a different set of queues or a single queue to support different versions of messages depends on the extent of the difference between messages. In the [versioning sample](http://nservicebus.com/docs/Samples/Versioning.aspx) the V2 message is a pure extension of the V1 message which can be represented by interface inheritance. Subscribers of V1 messages can receive V2 messages which are proper super sets of V1 messages. In this case, it makes sense to keep the same queue and only update subscribers as needed. If the messages are drastically different it may be easier to deploy a second set of queues. This has the benefits you described, namely isolation. You don't have to worry about messing up dependent components. However, this will have a bigger impact on your system because you have to consider everything that may depend on the queues. It may be that you have to deploy multiple endpoints and services at once to make the V2 roll out complete.

Comment: Yes, but at the same time operational overhead is one of the major things we introduce if we use multiple queues. One big win around using the minimum setup is reduced production monitoring effort. That's definitely and advantage.